# Variables being Reset in Methods

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a simple program that has a "player" and a "monster" and draws random numbers to lower health. I then want it to print in a text area. My variables monster and player are being reset to 0 everywhere except the FightTheMonster method. (sorry in advance for the sloppy code). When I have monster or player be printed in the playerDied or monsterDied methods, they print as 0 no matter what, this also happens in the main method.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    JTextArea textArea;
    static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    public static int player;
    public static int monster;
    private static void CreateAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Monster Fight");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComponent newContentPane = new Main();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
public static void FightTheMonster() {
    boolean loop = true;
    Main.player=10;
    Main.monster=10;

    while (loop == true) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        Random monsterroll = new Random();
        int m = monsterroll.nextInt(3) + 1;
        player = player - n;
        monster = monster - m;
        System.out.println("player health " + player + " monsterhealth " + monster);

        if(player <= 0) {
            loop = false;
            System.out.println("Player Died");
        }
        if(monster <= 0) {
            loop = false;
            System.out.println("Monster Died");

        }
    }
}


public void monsterDied(int monster) {
    Main.monster = Main.monster;
    System.out.println("monster health in void" + monster);
    if(monster <= 0) {
    textArea.append("Monster Died");
    System.out.println("Monster Died in void");
    }
}
public void playerDied(int player) {
    if(player <= 0) {
    textArea.append("Player Died");
    System.out.println("Player Died in void");
    }
}
public Main() {
    super(new GridLayout(0,1));
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));
    add(scrollPane);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.monster = Main.monster;
    System.out.println("Monster Health in Main Method " + monster);
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            CreateAndShowGui();
            FightTheMonster();

        }
    });
    Main juice = new Main();
    juice.playerDied(player);
    juice.monsterDied(Main.monster);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your static fields monster and player value when you define them:

```
 public static int player=10;
    public static int monster=10;
```

And because fight method runs after info string:  `System.out.println("Monster Health in Main Method " + monster);` default values zero is printed

Answer (score 0):

The main thing happening here is a threading / timing issue. You are calling the CreateAndShowGui and FightTheMonster methods on a new thread and running them using "InvokeLater". If you look at the console output, you'll notice this is happening after juice.playerDied and juice.monsterDied is being called. Here is the output I see when running your code:

> Monster Health in Main Method 0
>
> Player Died in void
>
> monster health in void0
>
> Monster Died in void
>
> player health 8 monsterhealth 7
>
> player health 7 monsterhealth 5
>
> player health 6 monsterhealth 3
>
> player health 4 monsterhealth 2
>
> player health 1 monsterhealth 0
>
> Monster Died

This shows you the order of how things are happening. So those playerDied and monsterDied methods are being called before you set the variables to 10.

I'm not a swing expert and not sure what the idea behind your program is, but you could try solving this by using invokeAndWait instead of invokeLater. That will result in the methods happening in the order you have listed them in the main method.

That said, as an additional improvement, I would probably create new classes with player and monster or something, instantiate them in the main method, pass them into the fightTheMonster method and not use static variables like you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even notice that, there isn't a real "purpose" in the sense that it was assigned or is trying to actually do something productive, I am just trying to learn java, and I _thought_ that I had learned enough to do something more exciting, since just following the tutorials is really boring, but clearly I need more practice.